# Are there any spells or features that give another player an additional bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions

Are there any spells or features that give another player an additional bonus action?

I am trying to find any way to get an additional bonus action during a round of combat above the standard one bonus action allotted due to having two features I want to use in conjunction with one another that both require a bonus action.

Comment: Which two features are you wanting to use in conjunction? A solution to your problem may involve another bonus action, *or* it might involve achieving the same result differently. The latter does require knowing what result you're hoping to achieve though. You can [edit] your question to include more information.

Comment: Related: [How many bonus actions can I take?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/87844/how-many-bonus-actions-can-i-take)

Comment: I've gone ahead and voted to close this as a duplicate. If you edit in your answer to SevenSidedDie's question, however, that might make it a distinct question. In that case do go ahead and flag the question for reopening--I (for one) am curious to see what you're planning =)